# VS skips data types creation lines - C

Tags: c, variables

so, I have a function in which I create multiple data types. I noticed while debug that VS just skips some of these lines.
this is the function:

```
void addNewUser(womenList* list, user*** manArr, int *maxArr)
{
//skips
    unsigned char temp = 0;
    char tempId[MAX_ID];
    int tempAge;
    char tempGender;
    int hobbies[4];
    char tempFirstName[16];
    char tempLastName[16];
    char tempUserName[16];
    char tempPassword[16];
    char tempDescription[212];
//not skips
    int idStatus;
    int i = 0;
//more code after that
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?
If you need me to add some more code, just say. thanks!

Comment: If there is no executable code associated with creating those local variables then there is nothing for the debugger to step through. In other words, don't worry about it.

Comment: The only lines not skipped here are ` unsigned char temp = 0;` and `int i = 0;` because they contain initilaisation code.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong, as such. The debugger is stepping over lines that define variables because there are no instructions associated with those definitions—there is nothing to debug, really.

All that's needed to implement `char tempPassword[16];` for example, is the allocation of 16 bytes on the stack. That's done as part of the preamble code for the function, along with all the other local variables of course, and usually it isn't something you'll notice in VC.

Some debuggers might step onto the opening brace of the function, and if you can switch to a window showing assembly instructions you might see something being executed there... but most of the time, most developers just aren't interested in that, any more than they're interested in the mechanics of passing parameters to the function.